# Can i change a function in system.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm wondering if i can change a function in system.dll
like instead of return 0; i change it to return -1;

and recompile it and use it again.

If yes how we can do it ?

Comment: This is really a bad thing to do, as it would break all the other code that relies on that function returning 0. Can you explain in more detail why you need to change it, maybe there is a better path than trying to recompile a core library...

Comment: What is your goal? A prank? And of course, you recognize that if you could do something like this, your "evilized" version of System.dll would not be signed by Microsoft, right?

Comment: Really difficult to imagine why do you need this

Comment: Just checking and testing things i'm asking if it's possible and if yes how we can do it :)

Comment: @demonplus For example to do what Fakes does without using Fakes. You edit the Microsoft assemblies, put a copy of them in the unit test folder, run your unit tests. Or perhaps because you want to use some `internal` class, or some class that has a `private` constructor. There are many, and it is very difficult/impossible to use them. There are many reasons...

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. You can't because you can't strongly sign the assembly you would produce with the Microsoft signature, and so all the other assemblies that reference the System assembly would complain (I know this because two weeks ago I tried to do something similar :-), but I didn't want to recompile. For me it was enough to use Mono.Cecil to directly edit a copy of the System assembly)

If you are writing unit tests, you could use [Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx) (requires Visual Studio Premium). It let you redirect methods of an assembly to your code, controlling the output and what the method does.

Technically you could do what the Fakes "library" does with this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/453065/ILRewriting-for-beginners But note that it is complex. You create a "runner" for your exe in C/C++. This "runner" (it is technically a CLR Host) can rewrite "on the fly" the .NET code of an assembly.